# iOS App Transfer + Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I recently transferred my iOS app from one developer account to another and now I am not able to send push notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging to my app. I have tried the following:

1. Updating the Team ID in the Firebase Console
2. Generating a new APNs Key and uploading to the Firebase Console
3. Re-configuring APNs on Apple Developer App ID page for the app of interest
   a) Generating a Certificate Signing Request on my local machine
   b) Uploading this Certificate to the App ID to configure APNs
   c) Generating a new certificate based off of this CSR
   d) Downloading this new certificate and saving in keychain
4. Trying to send push notifications from the Firebase Console

It is clear that the FCM Tokens are updated and that the problem lies within something that I am missing / forgetting to do on the Apple side to allow FCM to talk to APNs, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

We've encountered essentially the exact same issue. So far, the only way we've gotten push notifications to deliver to the client is by re-installing the App. Watching this to see if anyone else has a better solution!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer, just a general suggestion to reinstall something. Take a look again at [answer]